# Infinite loop to display links in local storage causing page to hang

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an HTML page, in which the user enters a series of URLs in a field, which are saved to local storage when submit is pressed. In another page, the contents of each of those links have to be displayed f0r 10 seconds (1000 ms) in an iframe in an infinite loop. My code is given below:

**saving links to local storage:** (partial)

```
$("#addLink").click(function(){

    var counter = 0;

    return function(){
        if ($('#link').val()){
            counter += 1;
            var rowContent = "<div class='row'>";
            rowContent += "<div class='col-md-2'></div>";
            rowContent += "<div class='col-md-8'>";
            rowContent += "<div class='panel panel-success display-link'>";
            rowContent += "<p><b>" + $('#link').val() + "</b></p>";
            rowContent += "</div>";
            rowContent += "</div>";
            rowContent += "<div class='col-md-2'></div>";
            rowContent += "</div>";
            $('#links-group').append(rowContent);       
            if ("localStorage" in window){
                    console.log("Key: " + counter + " Value:" + $('#link').val() + " in local storage");
                    localStorage.setItem(counter, $('#link').val());
            }
        }
    };      
}());
```

**The IFrame code**:

```
function loadLinks(interval){

    for (var i=1;i<=localStorage.length;i++){
        var link = localStorage.getItem(i);
        $('#page').attr('src',link);
        console.log(i + " " + link);
        setInterval(function(){}, interval*1000);
        if (i==localStorage.length){
            i=1;
        }
    }
}
```

The code `if (i==localStorage.length){ i=1; }` is causing the browser to hang. I am storing the links as key-value pairs in the local database where key is a counter and value the URL. (e.g. [1, 'www.google.com'], [2, 'www.msn.com'] etc.). Does anyone know how I can display the links in an infinite loop for a certain time interval without causing the browser to hang? Thanks in advance!!

Comment: don't use a for loop. Implement your own looping with Timeouts

Comment: don't think you realize what your loop is doing and how many intervals you are creating all at once

Comment: I think your logic is a problem here. Why don't you use an observer or something so you will change those links only when they have changed not looping. Also you set interval to an empty function with setInterval(function(){}, interval*1000); not to the function you want the itnerval be in.

Comment: @charlietfl Maybe you are right. I am trying to display the contents for 10 seconds, by putting the loop on hold, and then moving to the next one. My logic is not right, but I can't pinpoint the error

Comment: but that loop won't be put on hold...there in lies your problem. That loop will complete in a split second.... creating as many interval timers as there are items ... all at once. But also `i` will be the highest value by the time the interval callback fires